# How do I call a method in MainActivity class from Firebase Messaging Service class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to call a method in the MainActivity from Messaging Service. I have tried several ways, all from StackOverflow but none seems to work. Here is what I have done so far.

I simply want to show a dialog box once a notification is received.

This is the method in the MessagingServiceclass.

```
sendNotification(title, message);
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent("PushNotification");
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            pushNotification.putExtra("title", title);
            pushNotification.putExtra("code", code);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            savetodatabase(title,message);
```

The last line is saving the notification to an SQL database and is working well, which means that the code above it is being executed.

In my MainActivity class, I am calling a BroadcastReceiver using the code below

```
  BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (intent.getAction().equals(NOTIFICATION)) {
                    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    String code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
                    showDialog(title, message, code);
                }
            }
        };
```

However, the method inside the OnReceive is not being called.

I have also tried copying the method I want to be executed once the notification has been received in the Messaging Class but still it is not being called.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show the code where you register `mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver`.